# Code for highlighting current time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to create a table which will highlight the current time in red, but it isn't working. Could anyone give me any info as to what is wrong? Thanks. Here is the HTML and javascript:

..................................................................................................................................................................

```js
  var c = document.getElementById(block); 
  if (c != null)
        c.style.background = 'red';
         var d = new Date();
         var day = d.getDay(); 
         var minutes = d.getMinutes();
         var e = document.getElementById("info");
         
          if (minutes < 30) 
  hour = hour - 1;
 
 var block = "time" + day + ":" + hour;
  e.innerHTML = "Time is now " + block;
}
 
function startUpdate() 
{
  updatePage();
  window.setInterval(updatePage, 10 * 1000);
}
 
window.onload=startUpdate;
```

```html
<html>
    <head><link href="calendar.css" rel="stylesheet" type=“text/css"/>
    <script src="calendar.js" type=“text/javascript”></script></head>
    <body>
        <h1 id="info"></h1>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>Monday</th>
                <th>Tuesday</th>
                <th>Wednesday</th>
                <th>Thursday</th>
                <th>Friday</th>
            </tr>
            
            <tr>
                <th>8:30-9:30</th>
                <td id="time1:8"></td>
                <td id="time2:8"></td>
                <td id="time3:8"></td>
                <td id="time4:8"></td>
                <td id="time5:8"></td>
            </tr>
            
            <tr>
                <th>9:30-10:30</th>
                <td id="time1:9"></td>
                <td id="time2:9"></td>
                <td id="time3:9"></td>
                <td id="time4:9"></td>
                <td id="time5:9"></td>
            </tr>
            
            <tr>
                <th>10:30-11:30</th>
                <td id="time1:10"></td>
                <td id="time2:10"></td>
                <td id="time3:10"></td>
                <td id="time4:10"></td>
                <td id="time5:10"></td>
            </tr>
            
            <tr>
                <th>11:30-12:30</th>
                <td id="time1:11"></td>
                <td id="time2:11"></td>
                <td id="time3:11"></td>
                <td id="time4:11"></td>
                <td id="time5:11"></td>
            </tr>
            
            <tr>
                <th>12:30-1:30</th>
                <td id="time1:12"></td>
                <td id="time2:12"></td>
                <td id="time3:12"></td>
                <td id="time4:12"></td>
                <td id="time5:12"></td>
            </tr>
            
            <tr>
                <th>1:30-2:30</th>
                <td id="time1:13"></td>
                <td id="time2:13"></td>
                <td id="time3:13"></td>
                <td id="time4:13"></td>
                <td id="time5:13"></td>
            </tr>
            
            <tr>
                <th>2:30-3:30</th>
                <td id="time1:14"></td>
                <td id="time2:14"></td>
                <td id="time3:14"></td>
                <td id="time4:14"></td>
                <td id="time5:14"></td>
            </tr>
            
            <tr>
                <th>3:30-4:30</th>
                <td id="time1:15"></td>
                <td id="time2:15"></td>
                <td id="time3:15"></td>
                <td id="time4:15"></td>
                <td id="time5:15"></td>
            </tr>
            
            <tr>
                <th>4:30-5:30</th>
                <td id="time1:16"></td>
                <td id="time2:16"></td>
                <td id="time3:16"></td>
                <td id="time4:16"></td>
                <td id="time5:16"></td>
            </tr>
            
            <tr>
                <th>5:30-6:30</th>
                <td id="time1:17"></td>
                <td id="time2:17"></td>
                <td id="time3:17"></td>
                <td id="time4:17"></td>
                <td id="time5:17"></td>
            </tr>
            
            <tr>
                <th>6:30-7:30</th>
                <td id="time1:18"></td>
                <td id="time2:18"></td>
                <td id="time3:18"></td>
                <td id="time4:18"></td>
                <td id="time5:18"></td>
            </tr>
            
            <tr>
                <th>7:30-8:30</th>
                <td id="time1:19"></td>
                <td id="time2:19"></td>
                <td id="time3:19"></td>
                <td id="time4:19"></td>
                <td id="time5:19"></td>
            </tr>
            
            <tr>
                <th>8:30-9:30</th>
                <td id="time1:20"></td>
                <td id="time2:20"></td>
                <td id="time3:20"></td>
                <td id="time4:20"></td>
                <td id="time5:20"></td>
            </tr>
            
            <tr>
                <th>9:30-10:30</th>
                <td id="time1:21"></td>
                <td id="time2:21"></td>
                <td id="time3:21"></td>
                <td id="time4:21"></td>
                <td id="time5:21"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're trying to get `document.getElementById(block)` *looooong* before you actually do `block = ...`. And you expect this to work... why?

Comment: I see. Is anything else wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The main issue is indeed the ordering of your javascript. First of all, I assumed the top line of the program is cut off in your snippet and that it should be the beginning of the "UpdatePage" function.

Here is my restructuring of yours:

```
function updatePage() {
    var d = new Date();
    var day = d.getDay(); 
    var minutes = d.getMinutes();

    // I had to add this line because 'hour' wasn't defined.
    var hour = d.getHours();

    if (minutes < 30) 
        hour = hour - 1;

    // 'block' uses the results of your date manipulation 
    // so it must be defined after they are set up but as
    // 'Niet the Dark Absol' said it should also be before
    // it is used below as well.
    var block = "time" + day + ":" + hour;

    var c = document.getElementById(block); 
    if (c != null)
        c.style.background = 'red';

    var e = document.getElementById("info");
    e.innerHTML = "Time is now " + block;
}
```

I think those are the majority of the changes. I made a jsFiddle version of this exact version for you with one exception. I made it so that at the top you can specify a date since the current date/time for ME at least isn't currently in the range used here at all.

Check it out: http://jsfiddle.net/Lanlost/z0qgn9wj/

Let me know if you have any further questions. You're getting there =)\

Comment: I also made a secondary version with a few other changes. They are not necessary just things that might make the writing more manageable. They are purely my opinion but they might be useful. Since it's not directly relevant to the question and for you specifically I'm attaching a link via this comment instead of updating the answer.

It is at: http://jsfiddle.net/Lanlost/z0qgn9wj/1/

Answer (score 0):

So, you have a few errors, made several fixes to the code in a JSFiddle.

Of note, you didn't have any actual page update function running, your column IDs were off, and a few other things, take a look: https://jsfiddle.net/huucmhvu/2/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
function updatePage(){

    var d = new Date();
   //get the day plus two (to adjust for the first column and the fact that our IDs start at 1 not 0 )
    var day = d.getDay()+2; 
    var hour = d.getHours(); 
    var minutes = d.getMinutes();
    var e = $("#info");
    if (minutes < 30) {
        hour = hour - 1;
    }
    var block = "time"+day + "-" + hour;
    $(e).html( "Time is now " + block);
    var c = $('#'+block);
    if (c.length>0){
        c.css('background','red');
    }
}
function startUpdate() 
{
  updatePage();
  window.setInterval(updatePage, 10 * 1000);
}
 startUpdate();
```

});

There are a lot of fixups I would do if this were to be production quality code but your example is functioning now with the times and proper dates highlighting.

Comment: Quick note, this doesn't currently work since it is 2 in the morning and the time starts at 8 in the morning.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function getHourIn12(hour) {
  if (hour > 12) {
    return hour - 12;
  } else {
    return hour;
  }
}

function updatePage() {
  var date = new Date();
  var min = date.getMinutes();
  var hourIn24 = date.getHours();
  var hourIn12 = getHourIn12(hourIn24);
  var lowerHour = 0;
  
  if (min <= 30) {
    lowerHour = (hourIn24 - 1);
  } else {
    lowerHour = hourIn24;
  }
  
  targetHeadings = $('#time' + date.getDay() + '-' + lowerHour);
  targetHeadings.text('');
  targetHeadings.css('background', 'red').text(hourIn12 + ':' + min);
  
  console.log(targetHeadings);
}

timer = window.setInterval(updatePage, 1000);
```

```css
td, th{
  min-width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  }

td{
  color: white;
  }
th{
  background: grey;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
    <head><link href="calendar.css" rel="stylesheet" type=“text/css"/>
    <script src="calendar.js" type=“text/javascript”></script></head>
    <body>
        <h1 id="info"></h1>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>Monday</th>
                <th>Tuesday</th>
                <th>Wednesday</th>
                <th>Thursday</th>
                <th>Friday</th>
            </tr>
            
            <tr>
                <th>8:30-9:30</th>
                <td id="time1-8"></td>
                <td id="time2-8"></td>
                <td id="time3-8"></td>
                <td id="time4-8"></td>
                <td id="time5-8"></td>
            </tr>
            
            <tr>
                <th>9:30-10:30</th>
                <td id="time1-9"></td>
                <td id="time2-9"></td>
                <td id="time3-9"></td>
                <td id="time4-9"></td>
                <td id="time5-9"></td>
            </tr>
            
            <tr>
                <th>10:30-11:30</th>
                <td id="time1-10"></td>
                <td id="time2-10"></td>
                <td id="time3-10"></td>
                <td id="time4-10"></td>
                <td id="time5-10"></td>
            </tr>
            
            <tr>
                <th>11:30-12:30</th>
                <td id="time1-11"></td>
                <td id="time2-11"></td>
                <td id="time3-11"></td>
                <td id="time4-11"></td>
                <td id="time5-11"></td>
            </tr>
            
            <tr>
                <th>12:30-1:30</th>
                <td id="time1-12"></td>
                <td id="time2-12"></td>
                <td id="time3-12"></td>
                <td id="time4-12"></td>
                <td id="time5-12"></td>
            </tr>
            
            <tr>
                <th>1:30-2:30</th>
                <td id="time1-13"></td>
                <td id="time2-13"></td>
                <td id="time3-13"></td>
                <td id="time4-13"></td>
                <td id="time5-13"></td>
            </tr>
            
            <tr>
                <th>2:30-3:30</th>
                <td id="time1-14"></td>
                <td id="time2-14"></td>
                <td id="time3-14"></td>
                <td id="time4-14"></td>
                <td id="time5-14"></td>
            </tr>
            
            <tr>
                <th>3:30-4:30</th>
                <td id="time1-15"></td>
                <td id="time2-15"></td>
                <td id="time3-15"></td>
                <td id="time4-15"></td>
                <td id="time5-15"></td>
            </tr>
            
            <tr>
                <th>4:30-5:30</th>
                <td id="time1-16"></td>
                <td id="time2-16"></td>
                <td id="time3-16"></td>
                <td id="time4-16"></td>
                <td id="time5-16"></td>
            </tr>
            
            <tr>
                <th>5:30-6:30</th>
                <td id="time1-17"></td>
                <td id="time2-17"></td>
                <td id="time3-17"></td>
                <td id="time4-17"></td>
                <td id="time5-17"></td>
            </tr>
            
            <tr>
                <th>6:30-7:30</th>
                <td id="time1-18"></td>
                <td id="time2-18"></td>
                <td id="time3-18"></td>
                <td id="time4-18"></td>
                <td id="time5-18"></td>
            </tr>
            
            <tr>
                <th>7:30-8:30</th>
                <td id="time1-19"></td>
                <td id="time2-19"></td>
                <td id="time3-19"></td>
                <td id="time4-19"></td>
                <td id="time5-19"></td>
            </tr>
            
            <tr>
                <th>8:30-9:30</th>
                <td id="time1-20"></td>
                <td id="time2-20"></td>
                <td id="time3-20"></td>
                <td id="time4-20"></td>
                <td id="time5-20"></td>
            </tr>
            
            <tr>
                <th>9:30-10:30</th>
                <td id="time1-21"></td>
                <td id="time2-21"></td>
                <td id="time3-21"></td>
                <td id="time4-21"></td>
                <td id="time5-21"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: > Today is Sunday, so it will not highlight any cell.. Try it changing system date/time